# Python way to detect language ISO code

Tags: python, nlp

I have millions of sentence fragments and I am trying to determine if each is in English, French, Japanese, or Germ. Is there a python program to do this?

```
s1 = 'This is where lies a person'
s2 = 'ボウリング・フォー・コロンバイン(字幕版)'
s3 = 'Ep. 2448 : épisode du 12 mars 2014 (Plus belle la vie, Saison 10, Vol. 6)

language_of_string(s1) ==> EN
language_of_string(s2) ==> JP
language_of_string(s3) ==> FR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[guess_language](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/guess-language)

```
s1 = 'This is where lies a person'
s2 = 'ボウリング・フォー・コロンバイン(字幕版)'
s3 = 'Ep. 2448 : épisode du 12 mars 2014 (Plus belle la vie, Saison 10, Vol. 6)'

import guess_language
print guess_language.guessLanguage(s1)
print guess_language.guessLanguage(s2)
print guess_language.guessLanguage(s3)
en
ja
fr
```

Answer (score 2):

try langid with source code
https://github.com/saffsd/langid.py

```
>>> import langid
>>> langid.classify("This is a test")
('en', 0.99999999099035441)
```